# Distinguish between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in a function template

Tags: c++, templates, reference

Is there a way to let the compiler distinguish whether the passed variable is a reference or not, without explicitly specifying it using e.g. `<int &>`? The following example displays '1', whereas I expected a '2':

```
template <typename Type>
void fun(Type)
{
    cout << 1 << '\n';
}

template <typename Type>
void fun(Type &)
{
    cout << 2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int &ref = x;
    fun(ref);
}
```

I also tried to use `std::ref`, but I don't get it to work.

Comment: What compiler are you using? That does not look like valid C++, those calls should be ambiguous, I believe. Most compilers agree: https://godbolt.org/z/ovW5QB

Comment: @DeducibleSteak Yeah that's what I think as well, but why does compiler allow defining such methods? (I'm using Apple Clang, and it allows me to define both methods)

Comment: @farzadshbfn That's most likely a bug in your compiler.

Comment: References don't really exist as far as the compiler is concerned. All a reference is is a different name for a variable. Like @DeducibleSteak I'd expect the compiler to complain about ambiguity.

Comment: @DeducibleSteak It does detect ambiguity on call-site, but it doesn't say it while defining the functions. weird.

Comment: @farzadshbfn There's no problem with the definitions, valid calls exist that resolve unambiguously: https://godbolt.org/z/9CAWsP

Comment: @DeducibleSteak You're right. I didn't notice since I'm using an older version of g++ (8.3.0) which does not throw an error.

Comment: @JasperKoning I'm curious, _why_ would you want to differentiate like that?

Comment: That got my interest, Jasper, so I tried to build the program using g++ 8.3.0 and got the expected error. Compiler options used: `-std=c++17 -O0 -g3 -pg -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -Wuninitialized` What options do you use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I don't need it necessarily. But it can be useful to have an overloaded variant that lets you pass the variable by reference. In those cases it might be nice if you would not have to specify which variant you want to use, but instead let it depend on the variable that is passed.

Comment: @JasperKoning, anyway, You will not be able to differentiate like that. The parameter types at the call site for both `fun(x)` and `fun(ref)` will be the same: `int&`. But I can't answer with authoritative links, will leave it for someone with more language-lawyer-foo.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, I have to correct myself, I was using std::ref, so using `fun(std::ref(ref))` does not produce the error

Comment: @DeducibleSteak You will notice I also have not tried to answer. Somewhere in the 2000-or-so pages of the C++ Standard is the quote that definitely answers this, and I suck at finding them.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<Type>::value>>
void fun(Type)
{
    std::cout << 1 << '\n';
}

template <typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<Type>::value>>
void fun(Type &)
{
    std::cout << 2 << '\n';
}

int main() {

    int x = 0;
    int &ref = x;
    fun<int&>(ref); // Call the one that you want, and don't leave the compiler decide which one you meant

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```